# Umbraco 11 Custom Routes to hide query string keys

Tags: umbraco

I have an umbraco 11 project.

In that project I have used route hijacking to create my own custom controller (which inherits from rendercontroller)

The problem I am trying to solve is that the URL the user sees is MyDomain.com/mypage?number=123, but I want to use routing so that what they actuaklly type & see is MyDomain.com/123

Using a normal MVC controller this would be a 2 minute job, doing it in umbraco.. well Im not even sure it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a custom IContentFinder and a IUrlProvider, this way you can use another URL than the standard URL that Umbraco will generate:

https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/reference/routing/request-pipeline/icontentfinder